# Duplicate rows by list len in dataframe and add them as index

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one of the columns has 2 or more elements inside a list format, like the following:

```
                     Email                           Country
0              john@gmail.com                    [Czech Republic, Singapore, United Kingdom]
1             Davies2@gmeail.com                 [Singapore, United Kingdom]   
2              SooEng@gmail.com                  [United Kingdom, Czech Republic]
```

I need to do the following:
- Duplicate the number of rows by list lenght in "Country" (so for example, first row would be duplicated twice)
- For each row, I would need to have as index one of the list elements (so for example, one of them would be Czech Republic, the other row Singapore and the other row United Kingdow as index).

Does someone know how could I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.explode()` to 'duplicate' the rows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['john@gmail.com', ['Czech Republic', 'Singapore', 'United Kingdom']],
                   ['Davies2@gmeail.com', ['Singapore', 'United Kingdom']],
                   ['SooEng@gmail.com', ['United Kingdom', 'Czech Republic']]
                  ], columns = ['Email', 'Country'])
df.explode('Country')
```

Result:

```
                Email         Country
0      john@gmail.com  Czech Republic
0      john@gmail.com       Singapore
0      john@gmail.com  United Kingdom
1  Davies2@gmeail.com       Singapore
1  Davies2@gmeail.com  United Kingdom
2    SooEng@gmail.com  United Kingdom
2    SooEng@gmail.com  Czech Republic
```

To set the index use:

```
df.explode('Country').set_index('Country')
```

Comment: Hello Rene, thanks for the quick reply! I am getting the error that dataframe has no attribute "explode"

Comment: What version of pandas do you use?

Comment: Yeah, just checked I need to update Pandas version, thanks!